# Unable to Publish Azure Cloud Service From Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I get a red cross (see below) after selecting the subscription I want to publish my Azure Cloud Service to. I cannot continue with publishing and there is no error just a red cross. I did not create the subscription but I have been added as a user and assigned the role of Owner.  I have another subscription (free-trial) which I can publish to no problem.  What does the red cross mean?

[image]

Also I can create resources and use the account no problem through the Azure web portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get around the issue by installing the latest version of Azure SDK and publishing the WCF service directly as an Azure Web App as opposed to Azure Cloud Service.

However, I still don't know why I was getting a red cross with this particular subscription.